# Cannot load RJB (Ruby Java Bridge) on Windows

Tags: java, ruby, rjb

using

```
require 'rjb'
```

in IRB returns "true", but

```
require 'rjb'
```

in my application returns

```
cannot load such file -- rjb
```

Including 'rjb' into Gemfile does not solve the problem. What's wrong?

```
require "rubygems"
```

does not help.

rjb is installed.

I have Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Ruby you're using, you will require to load RubyGems first:

```
require "rubygems"
require "rjb"
```

You can check if `rjb` was installed as a gem using `gem list rjb` from a console.

Without more details about the version of Ruby you're using, guess this is the best I could answer it.

Comment: require "rubygems" does not help. rjb is installed. I have Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: If IRB is finding it and invoking your scripts from the console is not, that could mean IRB and your script are using different version of Ruby or have no access to the same list of gems. Please check `gem env` and from inside `irb` that they are indeed the same version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Gemfile of your project in this way, add a string:

```
gem 'rjb', '1.4.7' <- put version of installed rjb gem
```

Then save Gemfile
and do

```
bundle install
```

P.S. Sorry for my English =)